# Json Android Studio

Tags: android, json

i'm actually doing a work with some Json DATA in android , i'm familiar with JSON on JS but on android it's almost new.  May you help me please my problem :

i got this kind of Json :

```
 [{
    "id": 1348904,
    "name": "ameko_(kasu)",
    "post_count": 5,
    "related_tags": null,
    "related_tags_updated_at": "2016-01-18T02:20:50.225-05:00",
    "category": 4,
    "created_at": "2016-01-18T04:33:48.792-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:33:48.792-05:00",
    "is_locked": false
}, {
    "id": 1348897,
    "name": "amyenah",
    "post_count": 2,
    "related_tags": "5boys 1 amyenah 1 artist_name 1 collarbone 1 crop_top 1 earrings 1 giorno_giovanna 1 grin 1 hat 1 higashikata_jousuke 1 highres 1 interlocked_fingers 1 jewelry 1 jojo_no_kimyou_na_bouken 1 jonathan_joestar 1 joseph_joestar_(young) 1 kuujou_joutarou 1 lying 1 male_focus 1 midriff 1 multiple_boys 1 navel 1 neck 1 on_back 1 one_eye_covered 1",
    "related_tags_updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:05:24.193-05:00",
    "category": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-01-18T04:02:33.962-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:05:24.194-05:00",
    "is_locked": false
}]
```

And i'm trying to Get an array with all the "ID" of the Json.

Thanks a lot

Comment: did you learned how to parse json response in android?

Comment: are you trying to make a json object in android?, or you want to know how to use the above json in android?. let me know , so that i can post the answer.

Comment: Checkout [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) in the Android-documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this piece of code will help you.

```
String strJson="
  {
     \"Employee\" :[
     {
        \"id\":\"01\",
        \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",
        \"salary\":\"500000\"
     },
     {
        \"id\":\"02\",
        \"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",
        \"salary\":\"500000\"
     },
     {
        \"id\":\"03\",
        \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\",
        \"salary\":\"600000\"
     }
     ] 
  }";
  String data = "";
  try {
     JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);

     //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
     JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Employee");

     //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
     for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        //##########You get your ID's here##########
        int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString());

        String name = jsonObject.optString("name").toString();
        float salary = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.optString("salary").toString());

        data += "Node"+i+" : \n id= "+ id +" \n Name= "+ name +" \n Salary= "+ salary +" \n ";
     }
     output.setText(data);
  } catch (JSONException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: so i just have to use JSONObject  jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);      and    int id = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.optString("id").toString()); ?

Comment: You can do just that(but you will get only the first object) but it will be better(if you have more objects in a json,which you do) to go through them in a "for" like its done in the code I gave you. And then each "int id" you get is the id in your json.

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("Employee");  by what  should i replace employee ? because there's no name for my items

Answer (score 0):

Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library will make it very easier. Create a `User` class first for your array objects.

```
public class User {

    public String id;
    public String name;
    // rest of the elements
}
```

Then using Gson, try this -

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
User[] arr = gson.fromJson(yourJsonStr, User[].class);
```

Then the rest of the thing is pretty easier like you can do something like this-

```
ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(User user:arr){

            idList.add(user.id);

        }
```

You need to add Gson in gradle file -

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to declear json data correctly like shown below.

```
["Employee":{
    "id": 1348904,
    "name": "ameko_(kasu)",
    "post_count": 5,
    "related_tags": null,
    "related_tags_updated_at": "2016-01-18T02:20:50.225-05:00",
    "category": 4,
    "created_at": "2016-01-18T04:33:48.792-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:33:48.792-05:00",
    "is_locked": false
}, {
    "id": 1348897,
    "name": "amyenah",
    "post_count": 2,
    "related_tags": "5boys 1 amyenah 1 artist_name 1 collarbone 1 crop_top 1 earrings 1 giorno_giovanna 1 grin 1 hat 1 higashikata_jousuke 1 highres 1 interlocked_fingers 1 jewelry 1 jojo_no_kimyou_na_bouken 1 jonathan_joestar 1 joseph_joestar_(young) 1 kuujou_joutarou 1 lying 1 male_focus 1 midriff 1 multiple_boys 1 navel 1 neck 1 on_back 1 one_eye_covered 1",
    "related_tags_updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:05:24.193-05:00",
    "category": 1,
    "created_at": "2016-01-18T04:02:33.962-05:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-18T04:05:24.194-05:00",
    "is_locked": false
}
```

now you can call data correctly as we have put array tag above.